# $rootScope.$on event not firing

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to have a function fire off after a user logs in. I tried wrapping the broadcast in a timer because I saw some people suggest it but it doesn't seem to be working. Some people were having the problem that their controller wasn't initialized yet but I have the $on in the app.run so it should already have happened.

```
app.run(['$rootScope', '$http', '$cookies', '$cookieStore', function ($rootScope, $http, $cookies, $cookieStore) {

$rootScope.logout = function () {

    $http.post('API' + '/api/Account/Logout')
        .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = null;
            $http.defaults.headers.common.RefreshToken = null;
            $cookieStore.remove('_Token');
            $cookieStore.remove('_RefreshToken');
            $rootScope.username = '';
            $rootScope.loggedIn = false;
            window.location = '#/signin';
        });

}

$rootScope.$on('loggedIn', function (event) {
    if ($http.defaults.headers.common.RefreshToken != null) {
        var params = "grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=" + $http.defaults.headers.common.RefreshToken;
        $http({
            url: 'http://localhost:52644/Token',
            method: "POST",
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
            data: params
        })
        .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = "Bearer " + data.access_token;
            $http.defaults.headers.common.RefreshToken = data.refresh_token;

            $cookieStore.put('_Token', data.access_token);
            $cookieStore.put('_RefreshToken', data.refresh_token);

            $http.get('http://localhost:52644/api/Account/GetUserInfo')
                .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    if (data != "null") {
                        $rootScope.userEmail = data.replace(/["']{1}/gi, "");//Remove any quotes from the username before pushing it out.
                        $rootScope.userFirstName = data.FirstName;
                        $rootScope.loggedIn = true;
                    }
                    else
                        $rootScope.loggedIn = false;
                });


        })
        .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            $rootScope.loggedIn = false;
        });
    }
});
```

}]);

```
app.controller('signInCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$http', '$cookies', '$cookieStore', '$location', '$routeParams', '$uibModalInstance', '$timeout' ,function ($scope, $rootScope, $http, $cookies, $cookieStore, $location, $routeParams, $uibModalInstance, $timeout) {
$scope.message = $routeParams.message;
$scope.signIn = function () {
    $scope.showMessage = false;
    var params = "grant_type=password&username=" + $scope.username + "&password=" + $scope.password;
    $http({
        url: 'http://localhost:52644/token',
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        },
        data: params
    })
    //$http.post('http://localhost:52644/token', params, {
    //    headers: {
    //        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'

    //    }
    .success(function (data, status,
        s, config) {
        $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = "Bearer " + data.access_token;
        $http.defaults.headers.common.RefreshToken = data.refresh_token;

        $cookieStore.put('_Token', data.access_token);
        $rootScope.$broadcast('loggedIn');
        $timeout(function () {
            $rootScope.$broadcast('loggedIn');
        }, 100);
        $uibModalInstance.close();
    })
    .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.message = data.error_description.replace(/["']{1}/gi, "");
        $scope.showMessage = true;
    });
}
```

}]);

Answer (score 2):

You cannot broadcast up to (or alongside) a $rootScope event handler.  You can only $emit up to it.

```
$rootScope.$emit('loggedIn');
```

Per the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope)

> `$emit(name, args);` Dispatches an event name upwards through the scope
>   hierarchy notifying the registered `$rootScope.Scope` listeners.
>
> The event life cycle starts at the scope on which `$emit` was called.
>   All listeners listening for name event on this scope get notified.
>   Afterwards, the event traverses upwards toward the root scope and
>   calls all registered listeners along the way. The event will stop
>   propagating if one of the listeners cancels it.

Comment: I actually tried using emit first and that doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: @Rich then you'd need to create a small plunker or fiddle that reproduces the issue.  There are some pretty hard and fast rules on eventing in AngularJS so if that doesn't solve your problem, you most likely have another issue in your code that isn't apparent in your question.